# Do C preprocessing directives belong to the C programming language?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Do C preprocessing directives belong to the C programming language?

I think they don't because they are processed by a C preprocessor instead of an actual C compiler.

Thanks.

Comment: which directives you mean?

Comment: All the preprocessing directives, which are processed by a C preprocessor.

Comment: so you thing #define is not the part of the C language. Preprocessor is an integral part of the compiler, same as other stages of compilations

Comment: can you give any example? I'm not kidding, if you are able to give example of C preprocessing directive (which is not defined by user, but by language itself), you will be able to answer your question

Comment: The preprocessor is a separate language. You can use the C compiler without it, but few people do that. Most libraries completely depend on the preprocessor, especially for inclusion.

Comment: How do you define "belong to"?

Comment: it is defined in the C standard so it is part of the language

Comment: The "C-standard" defines the C language, the preprocessor (as a part of the translation phases)  and the standard library. Yet, all these things *could* be defined separately.

Comment: Also, if you read up on the history of C, the preprocessor was originally meant to be more separate from the C language than it is now. In modern C , however, you use prototypes and those need to be "included", so you will use typically use the preprocessor to do that, as it comes readily available with every standard compliant C compiler.

Comment: @PSkocik  Thanks. I think your first comment is what I have guessed, so I upvoted it. I am not sure how to put it, the C proper language?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only insofar as they are discussed in section 6.10 of the C99 (or later) C standard.  The standard is (likely intentionally) vague about the preprocessor, only discussing things that it *should* do, not defining a list of things that it *may* or *must* do.

Could you create a compiler for standard C that does not have a preprocessor?  Certainly, though it would be very inconvenient to use libraries.

Comment: Actually the word "should" is the most used one in the standard :) "must" is used 5-6 times mainly in the notes :)

Comment: actually a pre-processor is a separate tool from the compiler, at least in gcc world. So, the compiler does not have a preprocessor.

Comment: It is separate, but the standard actually does specify some behaviors.  The question wasn't whether it was a separate tool, it was whether it was a part of the language. @Serge

Comment: Although even in GCC, they are integrated to an extent: for example, the compiler has to interpret line number directives passed to it by the pre-processor.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer i just reacted to the phrase about a "C compiler without preprocessor" in the answer. -- It already is :-)

Comment: No preprocessor would also mean, _inter alia_, no comments and no \-newlines in your long strings...

Answer (score 1):

The C Standard precisely defines the behaviour of the preprocessing phase.  So it is definitely a part of the C language.

It's normal for implementations to deliver separate binaries for preprocessing, compiling and linking.  The standard is written in such a way that each translation phase could be performed by a separate executable.  But it's not a requirement.  In fact most compilers also allow all of those things to be done via a single command (e.g. `gcc foo.c bar.c`).